# PHP uploading photo and saving for each user technique?

Tags: php

Here's how I plan to handle profile pictures: I would make a folder name "pictures" and all users upload to that specific folder and each time they upload the picture gets incremented like 1 or something so 1.png, 2.png so on. But then for that user, I would store that url of that specific picture in a table in the database for that user. And then I could just run a query to display all of that person's pictures which they could then choose one to make their profile picture.

Could I get some feed backs or if it's totally wrong, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save as many pictures as you want and have them all on your database. If you want to keep all profile changes (and not discard whenever a student change his photo), you'll need to have a table with the file names and a flag like "current_photo", to know which one is the current.

As for the filename, I would suggest to just make a random number using the student id + current time for example.

```
$path_info = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = $path_info["extension"];
$filename = $student_id . time() . $extension;
```

or even hash it

```
$path_info = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = $path_info["extension"];
$filename = hash("sha512", $student_id . time() . $extension);
```

Comment: If student A has pictures 1-5 and student B has pictures 6-10, the student's would have a table which holds their specific pictures(1-5) and (6-10) for A and B. And All I would need is a current_pic boolean and that should be good right?

Comment: You don't really need to count the number of photos each student have, unless you want to limit it. And yes, saving all pictures to the table all you'll need is a boolean to know each one is the current.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm numbering them just because I want each photo to have a unique id.

Comment: Create a field on the table with auto_increment :)